# Let $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{-1}$. Find the splitting field of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^{-1}$.
I want to find the splitting field of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
I know that $\operatorname{minpoly}_Q (\alpha)$ is $x^3+x^2-2x-1$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is degree $3$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I can factor $x^3+x^2-2x-1 = \left(x - (\zeta_7 + \frac{1}{\zeta_7})\right) \left(x^2 + (1+\zeta_7 + \frac{1}{\zeta_7})x + \frac{1}{\zeta_7 + \frac{1}{\zeta_7}}\right)$ but then im unable to further factorize the RHS term. What can I do from here?

Comment: This cubic is one of those "famous" polynomials with the property that if $r$ is a zero, then $r^2-2$ is another. It follows that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the splitting field. The trick comes from the fact that if $r=2\cos x$ then $r^2-2=4\cos^2x-2=2\cos2x$. See also Jack's answer.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-2x-1%24&p=1) gives many older questions where this polynomial makes an appearance. Usually its zeros are considered also. I don't have the time to pick a good duplicate target here.

Comment: if $f(r)=0$, then $f(r^2-2)=r^6-5r^4+6r^2-1= (r^3-r^2-2r+1)(r^3+r^2-2r-1)=0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the insight! I can understand this part now.

Comment: A bit more [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1405365/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296677/11619). There really is a lot of repetition within the available material. Not clear that I picked the objectively best ones, so not voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will take a look at them!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen about your first comment: I am quite curious if it also follows that $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ is the splitting field of $x^3 + x^2 -2x -1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it possible to show this without Galois Theory? I am only a beginner in abstract algebra and hence I don't know any Galois theory.

Comment: @hello See the calculation eatfood made a few comments up. If $r$ is a zero, so is $r^2-2$. Repeating the dose, so is $(r^2-2)^2-2$. These are obviously in the field $\Bbb{Q}(r)$. If you can show that they are all distinct, then you are done. Hint: if $r=r^2-2$, then $r=$____, and these are not roots. If you are familiar with Vieta relations, you get an easier formula for the third root.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hmm okay, but if the roots are all distinct, why is the splitting field of $x^3 + x^2 -2x -1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ then equal to $\mathbb{Q}(r)$?

Comment: @hello A cubic has three zeros, so they are all in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an odd prime $p$, let $\alpha_p =\zeta_p + \zeta_p^{-1}$. It is  known that the cyclotomic field $K=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbf Q$, with cyclic Galois group $G\cong (\mathbf Z/p)^*$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by the automorphism $\zeta_p \to \zeta_p^{-1}$ ("complex conjugation") is the unique subgroup of order $2$, and its fixed field $K$ is the unique subfield $L$ s.t. $K/L$ is quadratic. By definition, $\alpha_p \in L$. Moreover, $\zeta_p$ is obviously a root of the polynomial $X^2 -\alpha_p X+1$, so $K/\mathbf Q(\alpha_p)$ is quadratic, and $L=\mathbf Q(\alpha_p)$ and is the splitting field of $\alpha_p$. This is a very classical result from Galois theory, so I wonder whether there isn't some additional question.

Comment: So $[K : \mathbf{Q} (\alpha)] = 2 = [K : L]$ where $L$ is fixed field of a subgroup of $G$. So $L = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Could you explain why $L$ is the splitting field of $\alpha_p$?

Comment: Because Gal(K/Q) is abelian, Gal(K/L) is automatically normal, so the extension L/Q is galois, hence contains all the conjugates of any of its elements.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 10k! Use the newly earned powers wisely :-)

Comment: Thank you. But what powers ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Ok got it, I'm still not too familiar with applying the Galois correspondence sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The conjugated roots of $\alpha=2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ are $2\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}$ and $2\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ **is** the splitting field of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, by the cosine duplication and triplication formulas.

Comment: Hi @Jack, thanks for the answer. I don't understand how you know what the other roots of $\alpha$ are. (Right now I am just taking an introductory course of Galois theory.) But if you could include the stuff mentioned in Jyrki's comments, I'd be happy to mark this as the accepted answer.